# How to control the balance of a floating object?

Tags: forces, water, density, equilibrium, weight

I have this 3D printed object which I hope to float water. I added my printed object to a piece of foam (Glued) and then gently put it on the surface of the water. Every time I put it, it flips over and my printed object falls into the water. Volume-wise the foam size should be enough to carry my 3D print.

[image]

**Edit**:
I improved my design and now it floats. However, I am looking to optimize a little bit. I would like to carry more weight.

If I increased the sphere size at the bottom (underwater) would that allow more weight to float on the top of the flat plane? Also, would that allow me to decrease the surface area of the flat plane?
[image]

(Note: 3D print weight is 4g)
[image]

Comment: This is a specific engineering problem, so it should be on Engineering SE. But your boat is flipping because it is narrow and the center of mass is too high. Put a weight on the bottom of the boat. I'd sink a nail through the foam and call it a day.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_stability

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is unstable; the center of gravity and the center of buoyancy are such that a small rocking of the object causes a torque that flips the object.  See bouyancy stability discussions online.  With this information, you can make adjustments for stability.